# How to join two tables of an SQL query where the second table is used to sort the first?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on understanding a php/mysql app's custom schema can be combined in a SELECT query but I'm not familiar with the relation. I'm a neophyte programmer and lack the capacity to describe this relationship in order to find specific information on the net. I'm looking for either some pseudo-code or technical term for the design of this schema.

Its simple enough to illustrate as you can see below. I've also tried my hand at the logic that would inform the SQL commands as pseudo code and that's where I decoded I had to ask for help (9_9)

This is a taxonomy schema using two tables. The first table contains terms and weight-based order (lowest to highest) values. The second table specifies the parent-child relationships of the first table. Interestingly the child weights in the first table act like the second value of a multi-dimensional array with parent *m* weight indexing the child weight *n*. Something like taxonomy_term_weight [*m*][*n*]

```
table_a                table_b on table_a.ID 
+-----+------+-----+...+-----+ 
| ID  | TRM  | WT  |...| P   | 
+-----+------+-----+...+-----+ 
|1    |  3   | [9] |...| [0] | 
|2    |  1.1 | [0] |...| [9] | 
|3    |  2   | [8] |...| [0] | 
|4    |  2.1 | [0] |...| [3] | 
|5    |  2.2 | [1] |...| [3] | 
|9    |  1   | [5] |...| [0] | 
+-----+------+-----+...+-----+ 
table_a = term table,
table_b = hierarchy table
TRM= TERM, WT= WEIGHT, P=PARENT
```

My attempt at pseudo code. Logically, to get the first item we need to find the record with a P=0 (meaning it has no parent, and in this scheme is itself a parent) AND its weight value should be the lowest (meaning its the first item). Something like this in pseudo code,

`table_a.ID=table_b.P=0 AND table_a.WT=[lowest value] //e.g. P=0, WT=5, Therefore ID=9;`

The resulting ID then is the parent ID to find the children records,

`table_a.ID=table_b.P AND table_a.WT[lowest value] //e.g. P=9, WT=0, Therefore ID=2;`

followed by,

`table_a.ID=table_b.P AND table_a.WT=[lowest value] //e.g. P=2, WT=0, Therefore ID=none;`

but what I want is the same parent, with the weight incremented,

`P=9, WT=1, Therefore ID=none;`

I understand stringing tables together, but this seems to ziz-zag or oscilate. What I quickly realize is there is a depth complexity I don't understand.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using an Order BY clause to sort your results?

Comment: I'm ignorant? :-( What is the SQL logic/code for when the order is in the form [m][n]?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlorderby.php/  The format would be Order By Column1 [ASC|DESC], Column2 [ASC|DESC].  Pick either ASC or DESC, it defaults to DESC.

Comment: That looks like it interleaves Col2 into Col1 which is the exact _ordering_ problem. Which makes it clear there are two parts to the problem: _depth_ and _order_.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the "with the weight incremented" bit at the end (incremented from what/where?) - but this can probably be added in easy enough to the below...so, off the top of my head and assuming a single query is wanted without any functions/sprocs or dedicated views, then something like this:

**[NOTE: This is hand written off the top of my head and may need some tailoring, spell checking and very likley optomising - it's also in asni sql to make it db independant (to some degree)]**

```
select ID3 from
( 
  select id as id1, min(wt) as w1 from table_a A1 Inner join table_b B1 on A1.id = B1.p
  where p=0
) Q1
inner join
( 
  select id as id2, min(wt) as w2 from table_a A2 Inner join table_b B2 on A2.id = B2.p
) Q2
on Q1.id1 = Q2.id2
inner join
( 
  select id as id3, min(wt) as w3 from table_a A3 Inner join table_b B3 on A3.id = B3.p
) Q3
on Q3.id3 = Q1.id1
```

Edit: Added for clarity...
My understanding of the problem is this. From the example, we put in a P value of zero (this will probably be a variable in the final solution). This quesry (block1) joins the 2 tables a and b and returns an ID (2). This is required to be passed back in to the same query (replacing the P=0 with P=2 for the match again ID from table a).

At this point the example gives what currently is returned ID (5), but really wants to use the ID from block 1 (p=9), hence the third block here joins against the first query on P (output was as id1).

This means that the output for the second block (Q2) is not used at all, hence my comment about it above.

Incidently, all this is doing is using the join between table a and table b as a virtual table in itslef . This can be achieved with a view to which would make the query somewhat simpler (at least easier to read).

If this is not what is actually required, then I need a better explanation of how the steps are required to interact in the given example (what is desired, rather than what is current in the solutions). I do not foresee a problem here, it all seems doable at the database level in a single query. Some thought to indexing may be required though if these tables are sizeable at all (this is also where views can help - view indexes - or using a SPROC and temp tables which can then be indexed).

Comment: That was quick! Before I try my hand at testing it, will you explain something? `table_b B1 ON A1.id = B1.p WHERE p=0` is the "is parent" relationship. `table_b B2 ON A2.id = B2.p` reads to me as "has parent" relationship. What is the third block for?

Comment: Block 1 gets the first ID (9 in your example), the second block uses that to pull off the second id (2 in your example) - I don't know why you need this query at all I just worked from your example and assumed it has been cut down for the question. Block 3 uses the P=9 from block 1 as the feeder into ID as per the line "but what I want is the same parent, with the weight incremented, P=9, WT=1, Therefore ID=none;"

Comment: If I have the wrong end of the stick, then I will need you to elaborate a little so I can follow better. :)

Comment: Stick? Sorry, I don't follow your metaphor. Returning to the example, the first block gets {9} or {9,3,1}? and block 2 gets {2} or {2,4,5}, which would clarify if block 3 is {empty} or {5} (>_<) If the third block is there to get {5}, I'd get stuck if there were more than two children? I hoped the third block would be children's children, which isn't in the example, but would satisfy my sense of the problem.

Comment: And I don't want to reward your curiosity by ignoring it, I'll say I simplified the question from Drupal's taxonomy system. I omitted mentioning this simply because I didn't wish to prejudice the question since there is a drupal site at SE. I'm having difficulty with a [DA question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39233/how-to-add-parent-and-child-to-a-views-3-table-format-using-groupping-field) that is really a SQL question since Views is a query module for Drupal. I'm guessing I'll get further with a programming question than a black box question.

Comment: Added extra comment to the bottom - mostly regarding my read on the issue/solution. The metaphor (wrong end of the stick) simply means "if I have misunderstood" (it's an old British saying). Anyway, I'll check back tomorrow.